# Function for determine if date is within summer or winter time

Tags: php, date, timezone

Is it possible to determine if a given date is within winter or summer time (daylight savings)

Eg.

```
<?php
function isSummerTime($date) {

    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) within summertime) {
        return true;
    }         
    return false;
}
```